# Call Custom Function on the Click of Menu Item

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have created one custom submenu inside the lead menu as "**Process Leads**" and now i want to call one custom function with the help of that menu item. i have defined it as:

```
$menu_item[]=Array("index.php?module=Leads&action=callCustom", "Process Leads", "");
```

Now the question is that where should i have to defined this `callCustom` function in the code?

Comment: Not quite clear what you are asking, since it is refering a GET action to `index.php` the `callCustom` should be inside the `index.php` . Then `if($_GET['action']  == "callCustom") { callCustom(); }`

Comment: In index.php only it will create a ajax call on the Leads Module but i am not getting the where should we have to define this function in index.php we cant defined it. @AntonisTsimourtos

Comment: Can you share the code of `index.php`? You can define it almost everywhere..

Comment: include 'include/MVC/preDispatch.php';  
$startTime = microtime(true); 
require_once 'include/entryPoint.php';
ob_start();
require_once 'include/MVC/SugarApplication.php';
$app = new SugarApplication();
$app->startSession();
$app->execute();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php should never be changed in SuiteCRM - its a framework not a simple php script. So you have a proper way to do things.

Now to the code.

Actions are defined in the controller, in your case its the Lead module.

What I usually do is go to `modules/Leads` folder and I copy `controller.php` to  `custom/modules/Leads`.

Edit the file and create your custom action like

```
function action_customaction() {
            global $mod_string;
            if (isset($_REQUEST['yourParameter'])) {
           // Your awesome code here
                  }
}
```

Good luck with that